# How can I make have_posts() return posts ordered DESC by id?

Tags: order

How can I make have_posts() return posts ordered DESC by id?

Now the posts are in random order, each time I refresh page they change order.

Here is my code :

```
<?php if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit();
get_header( );
global $post;

?>
        <div class="ova_doc_wrap archive-doc <?php echo esc_attr( $number_column ) ?>">
            <div class="ova_doc_content">
                <div class="doc-list-item">
                <?php if( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
                        $id = get_the_id();
                    ?>
                    <div class="items-doc">
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="doc-icon-title">
                                <div class="icon-doc">
                                    <i class="flaticon-files-1"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="doc-title-item">
                                    <h2 class="doc-title">
                                        <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink() ?>">
                                            <?php echo get_the_title()?>
                                        </a>
                                    </h2>
                                    <div class="doc-meta">
                                        <!--<span class=" doc-meta-general">
                                            <?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ));?>-->
                                        </span>
                                        <span class=" doc-categories">
                                            <?php get_category_doc_by_id_doc( $id ) ?>                 
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="doc-readmore">
                                <a class="second_font" href="<?php echo get_the_permalink() ?>">
                                    <?php echo esc_html__( 'Vezi Document', 'ova-doc' ) ?>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                
                </div>
                <?php 
                    egovt_pagination_theme();
                ?>
            </div>
            
            <!-- end ova_doc_content -->
        </div>
        <!-- end ova_doc_single -->


<?php get_footer( );
```

Comment: `have_posts` doesn't perform queries or return posts, it just returns `true` if posts were found, or `false` if none were found. What you want is to look up `pre_get_posts` to modify the main query

Comment: Thank you @TomJNowell , I have found pre_get_posts and set order for query: `$query->set('orderby', 'meta_id' );` it solved my problem

Answer (score -2):

`have_posts()` is just a function that returns boolean value. You can use WP_QUERY instead and use order argument for ordering the posts.

Comment: this doesn't modify the main query, it replaces it and doubles the number of queries. You should filter the main query with `pre_get_posts` if you want to change it, not add a new query

Comment: the post didn't have the code when I replied.

Comment: that doesn't change it, you shouldn't use `new WP_Query` to change the results of the main loop, it's a popular mistake to make but causes performance issues and requires lots of workarounds to avoid mistaken 404s and broken pagination etc